# error=invalid_client_id in Android native app

Tags: api, oauth, android

i get the following error when logging out of my native android app that i built with Salesforce Mobile SDK:

```
error=invalid_client_id&error_description=client%20identifier%20invalid
```

This results in that the can't be used anymore because it just show a white screen with this message instead of the login screen. I have created the app with forceddroid npm package. I don't have changed a lot it's bacically the generated app that forcedroid creates. The consumer key that i use is from a connected app that i have created in my dev org. Even uninstall and reinstall does not help.

Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The Problem was that i added a file called bootconfig.xml.example as a template for bootconfig.xml in order to keep my consumer key out of version control.
bootconfig.xml.example contains xml without values and for some reason this file was taken for authentication instead of bootconfig.xml.
After i changed the name from bootconfig.xml.example to bootconfig.example.xml everything was working again and bootconfig.xml is used again.﻿